# Python RSA encrypt integers

Tags: python, rsa, pycrypto

I am trying to encrypt an integer using RSA.

I observed that I can encrypt a string but cannot encrypt an Integer.

here are the relevant code snippets:

Could not encrypt the integer, 4:

```
crypto:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>> input=4
>>> rsa=RSA.generate(1024)
>>> print rsa.encrypt(input,"")[0].encode('hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/pubkey.py", line 64, in encrypt
    ciphertext=self._encrypt(plaintext, K)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 71, in _encrypt
    return (self.key._encrypt(c),)
TypeError: must be long, not int
>>>
```

Now, I represent that number as a hex string, it works:

```
crypto:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>> input='\x04'
>>> rsa=RSA.generate(1024)
>>> print rsa.encrypt(input,"")[0].encode('hex')
09f7d33972b0b6b72136f8aef0c8ba4446afad0dcf65337cd8b6c48c3758f5455e19e9c1ecbd058d7f83bcaa1f860b1ea0197d83f91fa958e6c9a2664a7ebee77c41fbfc4d3960e98afc0d94d1af8a230c4d86fce53f4c7ac72ae40a8acb101b40de6d46fe8e3cb7265f253b410a95a255e5fad0d0438d1fc62ad1feb96d331f
```

Using the inspect module I checked the source code of the encrypt function of RSA object and it says it can encrypt both a string or an integer plaintext:

```
crypto:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>> rsa=RSA.generate(1024)
>>> rsa
<_RSAobj @0x29c1368 n(1024),e,d,p,q,u,private>
>>> print inspect.getsource(rsa.encrypt)
    def encrypt(self, plaintext, K):
        """encrypt(plaintext:string|long, K:string|long) : tuple
        Encrypt the string or integer plaintext.  K is a random
        parameter required by some algorithms.
        """
        wasString=0
        if isinstance(plaintext, types.StringType):
            plaintext=bytes_to_long(plaintext) ; wasString=1
        if isinstance(K, types.StringType):
            K=bytes_to_long(K)
        ciphertext=self._encrypt(plaintext, K)
        if wasString: return tuple(map(long_to_bytes, ciphertext))
        else: return ciphertext
```

So, why is it that when I try to encrypt a number using RSA object, it gives an error?

Why does it expect the input to be in long format and not int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback tells clearly the `rsa.encrypt` wants an argument of long type. If it is a string, it will turns it to long type.

```
rsa.encrypt(4L,"")
```

This will work and the `4L` is still a number but it is of type long.

I think the reason to ask a long is, to perform an encryption, you have to do some padding and then perform on the padded number. The number is very long, for sha1, it is multiples of 512. So for a number at least 512 int can not satisfy the need. So long is asked. And you can see from your result of inspect, it only do type conversion to string, no int. So if you pass an int, it is wrong. You have no method except hacking the source code of the module.

For a long, it returns a long. Maybe you can use this to do the encoding:

```
hex(rsa.encrypt(4L, '')[0]).rstrip('L').lstrip(0x)
'31bf11047cbe9115541e29acb5046d98f2a9bdc44d4768668e9119f8eca24bf24dfc4ac070950734e819675f93e1809859b750df63e8bc71afc7c83edfc6d2f59f495c8e378e0633f07e21672a7e862cfa77a6aede48075dec0cd2b1d8c016dade779f1ea8bd9ffa8ef314c4e391b0f5860cf06cb0f991d2875c49722e98b94f'
```

Also you can change the integer to bytes: `rsa.encrypt(input, '')[0].encode('hex')`. The input is `struct.pack('b', 4)`.

Comment: Yes, I know that it expects an argument of type long. My question was, why does it expect long and not int? Secondly, the reason I am not supplying the input as long is because you cannot call encode('hex') on a long object. It will result in an error. And the program that I am working on, it will always call encode('hex') method on the output of rsa.encrypt. This is why, I needed a way to send my input as an integer. Will \x04 be the same as the number 4?

Comment: Thank you for the update. The source code of script for encryption is already written. It asks me for an input that will be encrypted. Now, the source code is using, encode('hex') on the result of encryption as I have mentioned above in the code snippet. As I said, I need a way to send a number as an input to the encryption script and at the same time it should not be in long format. This is because the encryption script is using encode('hex') on encryption output. If you supply long as input, it will give an error. My question is, how do I give a number as an input in string format?

Comment: See the answer update. That's what you want I'm sure. :) I have tested it generates the same result as pass in a int.Excately what you have mentioned in the comment. 4 is \x04. @NeonFlash

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.x has two types of integers:

- The `int` type, which matches the C type `long` on the local platform. The precision is limited, but it is at least 32 bits.
- The `long` type, which has infinite precision.

The `encrypt` and `decrypt` method of the RSA key object in PyCrypto only works with `long` or binary strings, not with `int`. That is documented in the [PyCrypto's API](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html).

In theory, you could fix your code by forcing the integers to the required type using the function `long()`, but it is worth pointing out that your code will not be secure.

RSA encryption should be done with [OAEP padding](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP-module.html) and byte strings as input/ouput.

Comment: Yes, I can supply my input as long. But the problem is this: rsa.encrypt(input,"")[0].encode('hex') will give an error if input is in long format because you cannot call encode method on a long object. And this is the way the custom encryption script is written with which I am working. So, the only other way for me to pass my input as a number to the script is in string format. So, I wanted to know how can I give an input to the custom encryption script as a number in string format? I am using \x04 to send the number 4 as an input, any other methods? If I say, "4", is that the same?

Comment: @neon-flash What about hex(rsa.encrypt(long(input),"")[0])[2:]? Again, this is not secure at all...

Comment: I cannot modify the source code of this encryption service as I said before. It is already running on another machine, I can only give it an input. Since it expects the input to be in string format, I just wanted to know a way to send a number as an input. I can pack it as a byte and send it.

Answer (score 0):

[The input variable should be (byte string or long)](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#encrypt), however, unfortunately, it seems that in Python3 you cannot define long variables using l, L, or long() anymore.